# AutoDock-Vina in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda

good evening everyone, I have a problem when I want to install vina in the anaconda environment, I get this error and I can't correct it

```
(vina) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install vina
Collecting vina
  Using cached vina-1.2.3.tar.gz (95 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      Version found 1.2.3 (from __init__.py)
      error in vina setup command: 'python_requires' must be a string containing valid version specifiers; Invalid specifier: '>=3.5.*'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried many solutions, update the pip or install other versions of python but nothing works

Comment: https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/AutoDock-Vina/issues/194